# WSL2 Kali-Linux Win-KeX Stopped Working Without Root

Tags: sudo, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rdp, tigervnc

I have been able to use win-kex for a long time until today. Now I am having an issue where running kex gives me the following error:[image: Error connecting to the KeX server. Please try "kex start" to start the service. If the server fails to start, please try "kex kill" or restart your WSL2 session and try again.]
However, I am able to run `sudo kex` and it works fine, minus that I am now logged in as root. Weirdly as well, I am able to run `kex --esm` with very poor performance. It seems like such a weird error that I figured it can't hurt to ask here. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi The issue in the question does not seem to be related to their inability to use basic Linux tools. The issue appears to be a change in behaviour in a utility that has been working for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it on my own by modifying the executable for KeX. For some unknown reason the virtual "screen" had become locked by TigerVNC. The fix was to change the screen variable from defaulting to 1, to defaulting to 2. This may be a bad workaround, but I was tired and it worked. Will update if that changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo kex kill
sudo kex start
```

Now you must know what your KeX type is,
then look here and go to down in "Run Win-KeX":

https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/#optional-steps

My KeX type, for example, is: `kex --esm --ip -s`
(ESM = Enhanced Session Mode),
but your KeX can be different.

Comment: Why do you tell the user to look in [the “Run Win-KeX” section](https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/#run-win-kex) of the document,  but then link to the “Optional Steps” section?  And how does knowing the “KeX type” relate to your answer? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.